# how to send two different types of JSON response for a same request based on the input REST?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am new to REST API development and I am not using maven, I am just using eclipse to develop it.

Now I am getting a particular response say for example

```
{
"Status_cd":"1"
"status":"succ"
}
```

the above response should be in case of success and I want an error response like

```
{
"status_cd":"0"
"error":{
     "Error_cd":"2131"
     "Message":"unable to process"
      }
}
```

how to write my serialized class to accommodate these two kinds of response for same request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your REST controller, design the endpoint method so that it returns [ResponseEntity](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) object with wildcard parametrisation.

```
//Here your mapping annotation
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> getSuccessOrError() {

    //Body omitted
    //in case of success return new ResponseEntity(YourSuccessClass, HttpStatus)
    //in case of error return new ResponseEntity(YourErrorClass, HttpStatus)

}
```

Or you can either design your response class so that it contains both `staus` and `error` fields and initialize with value only the needed one.

Comment: Well thanks anyway i used  jackson annotation @JSONInclude(INCLUDE.NON_NULL) to get my thing working